# Some keys not working properly on MySQL Workbench for Mac

Tags: mysql, macos, mysql-workbench

I'm using MySQL Workbench 6.3.9 for Mac and I'm having an unexpected issue.
When writing SQL on the editor (any editor), it won't take my quotes (single or double) and some other special characters... For me to type a single quote, I'm having to hold Control key and then type the single quote...

Is this a know issue?
Is there a solution for this out there?

Comment: Same here.  Keyboard is configured as US-international since I need the dead keys for latin accents.  If I configure as standard US, no problem is detected.

Comment: That's a known problem and might be caused by the underlying editor control (Scintilla). That still needs investigation.

Comment: Same problem here. Quotes dont work, neither accented characters.

Comment: So, @MikeLischke, is there a tracker for this bug and more importantly, do we have any release dates for a resolution?

Comment: The public bug tracker is here: http://bugs.mysql.com (filter for Workbench bugs). We never give predictions for releases, but I guess it will take a while until this is fixed. At least you have workarounds like using a different input source. However, you can vote on the bug tracker. The more people complain the higher the priority to fix something.

Comment: yeah... i'm on `v8.0.17` and this is still an issue

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's a bug on 6.3.9 version for Mac. Quotes will only work if you're using "standard US keyboard layout".

But you can configure just the Workbench to use US keyboard layout, keeping others application with your native layout:

- Go to System Preferences > Keyboard > Input Sources
- Enable booth keyboard layouts (yours and the US)
- Check "Show Input Menu Bar" and "Automatically switch to a document's input source"
- Then with the MySQLWorkbench app active, change your keyboar to US using the icon in Mac's menu bar

It's not the preetiest solution. But it works.

Comment: Like you said, not the prettiest solution, but until MySQL get it's fixed (which I'm not sure they will for this version) this will do! Thank you very much for your solution

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a issue of this version. I came back to version 2.5.3, that is working well!

Comment: I don't really like 2.5.3. My experience is that this version was much more buggy.
The current version is more stable, editor issues aside.

Comment: Yeah, I also don't like 2.5.3, but at least I can work a bit better in this version :(