# How to enable the use quotes on MySQL Workbench 6.3?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, single-quotes

Since last `MySQL Workbench update (6.3)` it does not allow me to use single **quote (`'`)** or **double quote (`"`)** when writing a query.

Does anyone knows how to fix it?

Comment: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=85115

Answer (score 0):

That's a known [bug](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=86915). Here's a work around for mac though from [another thread:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43009643/some-keys-not-working-properly-on-mysql-workbench-for-mac)

> You can configure just the Workbench to use US keyboard layout, keeping others application with your native layout:
>
> - Go to System Preferences > Keyboard > Input Sources
> - Enable booth keyboard layouts (yours and the US)
> - Check "Show Input Menu Bar" and "Automatically switch to a document's input source"
> - Then with the MySQLWorkbench app active, change your keyboard to US using the icon in Mac's menu bar

Comment: The default shortcut for change between the keyboard available is ˆSpace, which disables the code completion from some IDE (IntelliJ for example). We can disable that shortcut in the tab "Shortcuts"->"Input Sources"